# GWT make suggestions after search with no hits

Tags: gwt, suggestbox

I have a database with words, and I use suggestbox of GWT to make search with suggestions.
I want, after a search that lead to no hits, to make suggestions with the closest words in my database.

For example, if the user inputs `"vadin"`, and this word doesn't exist in the database, but `"vaadin"` and `"avide"` do, I'd like to display a message like:

```
Do you mean "vaadin" or "avide"?
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could calculate the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the query string and some words in your database?

Comment: Hi simon-pierre. I first think of that but I'm wondering if there isn't a high level function in GWT that do that .? Thanks for your reply

Comment: No, I don't think that exists in GWT. Maybe you could find implementations of that algorithm in Java?